# Get the Page ID when the displayed product as has a different ID in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to run a function specific for one product that has a different ID than the page where is displayed. To this I run a function from my child theme functions.php.

I have tried page_id, post id, is_page but I do not get it to work.

My page-id is 8405, product id is 837.

My latest code try is:

```
    // Remove price variation on single product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_remove_variation_price' );
function my_remove_variation_price() {
    if ( is_page('8405') ) {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
    }}
}
```

How can I get the Page ID which is different frm the displayed product ID?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do the job and it will work specifically for your page ID:

```
// Remove price variation on single product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_variable_product_price', 1 );
function remove_variable_product_price() {
    global $wp, $product;

    $page = get_page_by_path($wp->request);

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && $page->ID == 8405 ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Amazing thank you! Was not aware you could combine those two but actually makes sense.

Comment: I have just tried the code but unfortunately it does not seem to work. It might have to do that the post-id is not properly read. The post-id of the page is 837. I have tried that but that does not work either. Or should I use product-ID?

Comment: @dzinee I have added a [product_page] shortcode on a page and it works… I have tried with different pages... So for me it works.

Comment: Did you try it on an actual product page? What post-id or page-id are you using?

Comment: I am using a page (not a post) where I add a product using the shortcode `[product_page id='8405']` in the content text editor… And it works just for the  variable product displayed on that page.

Comment: So what does that ID refer to? Is that the product number? The current page number WITH the shortcode? why would you use a shortcode actually? Is it not better to go on the actual product page?

Comment: @dzinee In woocommerce the default single product pages are not pages but a custom post which ID is the product ID… So as the post ID (the product ID) is not working for you, the only case is when you use a a product shortcode on a page or in another post… In that case my code works… Now I have no more explanations for you. I can't guess what you are doing in your web site and nothing seems to be working for you.